# Python client for elasticsearch has a problem with regexp support

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

The python client for elasticsearch does not work as expected with regexp. In the attached query example with the single word "platform" it works fine. Once I add another word like "java platform" it returns 0 hits. Same applies to words with capital letters. Wonder if the python client supports regexp properly? What might be the problem?

I have tried .* before and after the strings to check if encoring is a problem but to no avail. I need more complicated regex expressions but I don't succeed to make this trivial case work properly.

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
result = es.search(index="mydoc", body={"query": {"regexp" : {"Title" : "platform"}}})
result = es.search(index="mydoc", body={"query": {"regexp" : {"Title" : "java platform"}}})
```

No errors. The problem is 0 hits for simple cases like in the second example where the indexed document contains the string.

Comment: Please add the mapping of index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from the two search modes in elasticsearch: full-text search using a token for each word, and keyword search where the whole field value is indexed. Therefore, to search with regexp across words I should have employed the keyword mode as in:

```
result = es.search(index='mydoc', size =34,body=
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "Title":   "java platform"        }}
      ],
      "filter": [
        { "regexp":  { "Title.keyword": ".*[j,J]ava platform.*" }}
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

The match is just to speed up the search since the regexp contains .* in the beginning. The match will also match platform java and with any number of words in between while the regexp matches the specific order, first java and then platform (and they have to be adjacent).